# main layer with another layer not showing variables cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm having a strange problem... I have a custom class with sprite and booleans properties

In my main `GameLayer`, I have `CCLayerColor *my1layer` and in my .m section I have this code:

```
my1layer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(144,238,144, 255)];
[self addChild: my1layer z:5 tag:100]; 
[my1layer setContentSize:CGSizeMake(200, 1280)];`

//default start position
my1layer =ccp(s.width/2-420, s.height-s.height+180.); 

MylmageItem *postImage1 = [[MylmageItem alloc] initWithLayer:self];
[postImage1 release];
postImage1.postImageNum=CCRANDOM_0_1()*12 +1;

postImage1.postImage = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:(NSString*)[self assignPostImage:postImage1.postImageNum ]];
postImage1.postImage.position =ccp(my1layer.contentSize.width/2, my1layer.contentSize.height-my1layer.contentSize.height+80);
[my1layer addChild:myImage1.slotImage z:6 tag:101];’
```

code above does work and shows the images on layer, however when I try to access the property postImage1.postImageNum, it shows 0 always...

I do this:  `CCLayer *myLayer1 = (CCLayer*)[self getChildByTag:100];`  later to retrieve my object...

`MyImageItem *tmpImage1 = (MymageItem*)[myLayer1 getChildByTag:101];` from here I always get 0 when I do `CCLOG(@"postImage1.postImageNum %d",tmpImage1.postImageNum);`

How do I get data from `my1layer`?

Comment: I used this code on a single layer and it all works, but now I'm using multiple layers...

Comment: I forgot about the error message: [CCSprite postImageNum]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: post the function definition code of assignPostImage. And don't release the pointer postImage1.

Comment: MylmageItem *postImage1 = [[MylmageItem alloc] initWithLayer:self]; I notice that initWithLayer self initialize on main gamelayer and not on the m1layer, could this be the problem? @Krish the assignPostImage just assigns @"image.png"...

Comment: Problem solved!  part of the problem was the release of pointer postImage1, also I had to create a separate layer class that included the problems and methods... and bring that into the main gamelayer, and now it works...